# MongoEngine (python) - Extending the document class not working

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Im trying to extend the base functionality of the `Document` class like the following:

```
class DocumentExtended(Document):
    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}


class User(DocumentExtended):
    name = StringField()


User(name="John Smith").save()
```

The purpose is that I want to add some extra methods to `DocumentExtended` (but I've omitted those for brevity)

The **problem** is that the document does **not** get saved.

If I do

```
class User(Document):
    name = StringField()

User(name="John Smith").save()
```

it does get saved so I know it should work

Is there some weird trick I need to do to be able to extend the `mongoengine.Document` class **and** be able to save the models to the database?

Comment: okai I just refreshed the collection list in Robo3T and now Im seeing a collection called `document_extended` so it is being saved ... so the question becomes how do I extend the `Document` class without it being treated as a model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 hours of not understanding I finally read the docs

The `DocumentExtended` class must set `meta = {'abstract': True}`

```
class DocumentExtended(Document):
    meta = { 'abstract': True }
```

Comment: Here is the documentation on [Abstract Document classes in MongoEngine](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#abstract-classes)